# Flutter block scroll of PageView inside another PageView

Tags: flutter

I have the following Widget which displays vertically a list of pictures of some recipes, and when swipe to the right page of each of these recipes, it goes to its description page. The problem here is that when I go to `DescriptionScreen`, I can scroll down and go to other recipies' `RecipeScreen`. I want to block that, to allow vertical scroll only when user is on `RecipeScreen`, else if he is on `DescriptionScreen`, to be able just to swipe to left and continue scrolling. How it would be possible to achieve that?

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: PageView.builder(
              controller: verticalPageController,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemCount: recipes.length,
              allowImplicitScrolling: true,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return PageView(
                  controller: pageControllers[index],
                  children: [
                    RecipeScreen(
                      recipe: recipes[index],
                      onRecipeDelete: onRecipeDelete,
                      ),
                    ),
                    DescriptionScreen(
                      recipeId: recipes[index].id,
                      onRecipeSave: onRecipeSave,
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          SafeArea(
            top: false,
            child: Container(height: 0),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(
        page: currentPage,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a onPageChanged to your horizontal PageViews and when the user goes to the `DescriptionScreen`, you set the physics of your vertical PageView to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`.

High level code:

```dart
class MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  ScrollPhysics physics;
  
  void setScrollPhysics(ScrollPhysics physics) {
    setState(() {
      this.physics = physics
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: //...
        PageView.builder(
          controller: verticalPageController,
          // ...
          physics: physics, // this line will enable / disable scroll
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            return PageView(
              controller: pageControllers[index],
              onPageChanged: (page) {
                // enable / disable vertical scrolling depending on page
                setScrollPhysics(page == 1 ? NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() : null);
              }
            )
          }
        )
    );
  }
}
```